ICS is not auto scheduling multiple events in Google calendar
I am generating an email with an attached .ics file which contains multiple events.
When the file is imported into outlook or google, the multiple events are created properly.
I'm struggling though, as the attachment is not automatically adding the banner in Gmail to add ALL events to Calendar, only the first event is added.
gmail banner
I am unable to find an answer on how to fix this or if Google has a limit of events to auto schedule.
Could it perhaps be happening because an error in the .ics file?
I have uploaded to .ics validators and tried importing the .ics, and they all create all the events properly.
I want to make sure the user experience is easy for gmail users and they can just click "add to calendar" for multiple events.
